# Bash script, syntax on OR statement

Tags: bash

Can someone tell me why this script isnt working? I'm getting

```
./FileDirTest.sh: line 10: [: missing `]'
./FileDirTest.sh: line 10: n: command not found
./FileDirTest.sh: line 13: [: missing `]'
./FileDirTest.sh: line 13: n: command not found
```

Here is my script.

```
if [ -d "$PASSED1" ]
then echo "Do you want to execute whole directory?(Y/N)"
     read answer
     if [ "$answer" == "y" || "$answer" == "Y" ] ;
     then echo "Execute"
     fi
     if [ "$answer" == "n" || "$answer" == "N" ] ;
     then echo "No"
          exit 1
     fi
fi
```

Im sure it is something simple. I new to all of this.

Comment: Try [shellcheck](http://shellcheck.net), it autodetects common syntax issues like this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`||` is not a valid operator for the `[` command; you can only use it to *join* two distinct `[` commands:

```
if [ "$answer" = "y" ] || [ "$answer" = "Y" ];
```

You can, however, use `||` inside `bash`'s conditional command:

```
if [[ "$answer" = "y" || "$answer" = "Y" ]];
```

---

The first of the two errors occurs because `||`, being a special shell operator, indicates that the previous command is complete, but `[` requires `]` be given as the final argument. The second error occurs because the value of `$answer`, immediately following `||`, is taken as the name of the command to run.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Chepner's answer, you can also use, bash `-o` operator,

```
 if [ "$answer" == "y" -o "$answer" == "Y" ]; then
      echo "Execute"
 else
      echo "No"
      exit 1
 fi
```

Comment: `-o` is not recommended; it's an extension to the POSIX standard that introduces possible ambiguities in the parser, as `[` with more than 4 arguments is not well defined.